# HtmlUnitDriver Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener

Tags: selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I created a java class called htmlUnitTest to do a test with Selenium Headless Testing. The class basically goes to the google site and writes a text in the search box of the site, does the search and takes the page title and displays the title in the Eclipse console.
When I run the test, Eclipse displays the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>       com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener
>       at htmldriver.htmlUnitTest.main(htmlUnitTest.java:12)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>       com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowListener
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 1 more

The jar file I used to import the HtmlUnitDriver class for my project was: selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.52.0.jar.

Below is the Java code.

```
public class htmlUnitTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.br/");

    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    ele.sendKeys("Teste");
    ele.submit();

    System.out.println("Título da página: " +driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}}
```

[image: htmlUnitTest]

[image: htmlUnitTestError]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HtmlUnitDriver is only a small wrapper around HtmlUnit itself. So you need all the dependencies of the selenium-htmlunit-driver also (in fact HtmlUnit with all the dependencies).

You can download the whole package here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases

Comment: RBRi then just add the htmlunit-driver-2.30.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar file to my project that the Java script will work?

Comment: No, you have to unpack htmlunit-driver-2.30.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar into some lib folder and then add all the jars as libs to your project. Or you can use some dependency aware build toolchain like ant+ivy, maven or gradle.

Comment: Sorry my fault, was confused... you are right, use the htmlunit-driver-2.30.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar instead of the driver jar. No need to unpack. Sorry

Comment: worked for me , download the jar which says dependency , that would be a huge a file